# how to optimize a gui with many widgets/Python/tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, optimization, widget

I have an application with many entries on it (like excel). When I run this application, it works fine until a certain entry, but when that entry exceeds the limit, the program freezes and even shuts itself down. How can I optimize these entry widgets?

Here is the code. You can change the number of widgets by increasing/decreasing the for loops in the make_grid function.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Run(object):
    def __init__(self):

        #Creating Sections of our window
        self.file_bar=tk.Canvas(win,width=108,height=36,bg="lightblue",highlightthickness=1)
        self.func_bar=tk.Canvas(win,width=972,height=36,bg="lightblue",highlightthickness=1)
        self.main_frame=tk.Frame(win,width=972,height=684,highlightthickness=1)
        self.file_frame=tk.Canvas(win,width=108,height=684,bg="lightblue",highlightthickness=1)
        self.file_bar.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.func_bar.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.main_frame.grid(row=1,column=1)

        self.file_frame.grid(row=1,column=0)

        self.main_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.main_frame)
        self.main_canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.main_canvas.configure(width=942,height=664)
        
        
        #Creating Scrollbar
        self.Yscrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(self.main_frame,orient="vertical",command=self.main_canvas.yview,highlightthickness=1)
        self.Yscrollbar.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="ns")
        self.Xscrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(self.main_frame,orient="horizontal",command=self.main_canvas.xview,highlightthickness=1)
        self.Xscrollbar.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="ew")
        
        

        #Creating frame inside of main_frame
        self.grid_frame=tk.Frame(self.main_canvas,bg="lightblue",highlightthickness=1)
        


        # Configure the canvas to scrollable
        self.main_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.Yscrollbar.set, xscrollcommand=self.Xscrollbar.set)
        self.main_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.grid_frame, anchor="nw")  # Attach the frame to the canvas
        # Configure the scrollable region of the canvas
        self.main_canvas.bind("<Configure>",lambda e:self.main_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.main_canvas.bbox("all")))
        
        
        self.make_grid()
    def make_grid(self):
        
        self.columns=[]
        
        for i in range (0,30):
            rows=[]
            for j in range(0,30):
                cell=tk.Entry(self.grid_frame,width=4,bg="lightblue",highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=1)
                cell.grid(row=j,column=i)
                rows.append(cell)
            self.columns.append(rows)
        

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("1080x720")
win.title("UTM")
Run()
win.mainloop()
```

`

Comment: I think we need more information. I can't see why a tkinter app would freeze with just 30 entries. What number do you use to see the problem?

Comment: Actually, it's more about experiencing frame drops rather than freezing. Like tkinter can't handle it, to many things going on at the same time.
See the video, https://youtu.be/2ClAXl727P4 it was 50x50 btw. and my computer is too powerful for this job so the computer is not the issue .

Comment: I can see how tkinter might get laggy with over 3,600 widgets on screen at one time. There's probably not much you can do about it other than to only create as many widgets as can be visibly seen, and write some custom scrollbar code to scroll them.